# Where is rep shown on mobile sites?

Tags: support, mobile-web, top-bar, reputation-display

In the top bar of the mobile site, my reputation is not shown.

How can I show it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tap on the Stack Exchange icon in the top left and your name, reputation and badges count are revealed.

[image: location of icon and resulting menu]

Comment: I read an article a few years ago where they were able to reverse-engineer text obscured that way. If you're paranoid...

Comment: Not paranoid, just heading off the flood of 'pls help me with this code' emails.

Comment: Have you made it to two years' worth of consecutive visits yet?

Comment: @NickStauner: Current status: *visited 1333 days, 743 consecutive*